# Batch file calling a Java program, and Java returns value to the batch file

Tags: java

How can the Java program return values that the batch file can see?
 What other options are there to accomplish this task, without using batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `System.exit(n)` the value is the exit code or ERRORLEVEL which the batch script can use.

You can also read the output of the program or the contents of a file written.

Comment: Is it possible to pass variables names (20 diffrent) from Batch to Java code, make Java search for variables' values, and return values to Batch file? What would be better solution for that? Thank You.

Comment: For that I would use a Properties file for input and output. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect `System.out` to file

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

or use some logging library like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/)